# Possible to gaussian eliminate matrix with a coefficient in front?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

Is it possible to use Gaussian elimination on a matrix with a constant in front, like the one below? Do I multiply in 1/6 at the Reduced row echelon form stage? Or after parameterisation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that one of the operations you can perform to reduce to row echelon form is multiplication of a row by a non-zero scalar. So if you take the matrix you have presented, multiply each row by 6, then solve the system you end up with, its solution will be the same as the matrix you started with.

Answer (score 1):

if $RREF(A)=R$, then if $c \ne 0$, $RREF(cA)=R$.

I will just let the first operation be multiply each row by $\frac1c$, hence you can just ignore the constant.